# How to create an Object who act as a False in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to do this

```
lol = Klass.new(values)

unless lol 
   print "false"
end

lol.other_method  # it is not nil or false, it is a Klass instance!
```

But lol, in this case, is not nil or false, but an object who can act as a false based on some internal value. I have this alternative

```
lol = Klass.new(values)

unless lol.to_bool
   print "false"
end
```

But it is ugly IMHO.

I was thinking in extend the FalseClass or play with == but without success. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's not clear : what is `Klass.method(values)` Is it `Object#method` ? It takes a method name as argument and returns a Method, which you can later `call`.

Comment: instead method, imagine a "new" or a constructor

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

This is one of those annoying cases where Ruby is not object-oriented. In OO, it *must* be possible for one object to simulate another (in fact, depending on whom you ask, this is the very *definition* of OO – remember that OO came out of simulation), but it is not possible to build an object which simulates `false`.

This is because, in Ruby, conditional control structures are baked into the language and don't translate into message sends, whereas in other OO languages they are just regular message sends (or at least translate into message sends, just like `for` in Ruby translates into `each`). For example, in Smalltalk, Booleans are actually implemented using the Church encoding of Booleans you know from Lambda Calculus, and translated to Ruby they look a bit like this:

```
class FalseClass
  def if(&block)
    # do nothing
  end

  def if_then_else(then_lambda, else_lambda)
    else_lambda.()
  end

  def not
    true
  end

  def and(&block)
    self
  end

  def or(&block)
    block.()
  end
end
```

And `TrueClass` is just the mirror image:

```
class TrueClass
  def if(&block)
    block.()
  end

  def if_then_else(then_lambda, else_lambda)
    then_lambda.()
  end

  def not
    false
  end

  def and(&block)
    block.()
  end

  def or(&block)
    self
  end
end
```

And then, instead of something like

```
if 2 < 3 then foo end
if 2 < 3 then bar else baz end
```

You would have

```
(2 < 3).if { foo }
(2 < 3).if_then_else(-> { bar }, -> { baz })

# using the new keyword arguments in Ruby 2.0, it almost reads like Smalltalk:
class FalseClass
  def if(then: -> {}, else: -> {})
    else.()
  end
end

class TrueClass
  def if(then: -> {}, else: -> {})
    then.()
  end
end

(2 < 3).if(then: -> { bar }, else: { baz })
```

That way, you can easily create an object which simulates `false` simply by implementing the respective methods.

In other cases, where some object really absolutely *must* be an instance of a specific class and not just speak the correct protocol, Ruby provides an escape hatch. For example, if a method *really* requires an `Array` as an argument, then it will first try to call `to_ary` to at least give you a chance to convert your object into an `Array`. The same goes for `to_str`, `to_int`, `to_proc`, `to_float` etc. But there is no equivalent `to_bool` protocol.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do this: https://github.com/peczenyj/Lazy-Bool - I choose Perl BTW. I will think about your example and try to do something similar em Ruby.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: **Don't do this**.

The long answer is that in Ruby there are *only* two things that evaluate as false: `false` and `nil`. Literally everything else evaluates as true.

Many applications depend on this behavior and will probably malfunction if you somehow manage to change this. It's like defining 1 to be an even number. It's going to cause problems.

Comment: in this case, the best option is add a .to_bool to evaluate this in boolean context, right?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj `an object who can act as a false based on some internal value` -> just add a `false?` method which answers that internal value and then `unless lol.false?`. It's not ugly, but good Ruby duck typing, if I don't mistake.

Comment: Adding a `false?` method seems more than a little strange, especially considering `false.false?` would be an undefined method.