# Ruby memoization and Null Object pattern

Tags: ruby

Hello Rubyist out there,

Was wondering if it's possible to use Ruby's memoization operator `||=` (i.e: `a || a = b` when writing `a ||= b`) could be used on custom plain old ruby classes that are supposed to follow the [null object patern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object).

For example, say I have a class like:

```
class NoThing
    def status
       :cancelled
    end

    def expires_on
       0.days.from_now
    end

    def gateway
      ""
    end
end
```

Which I use in the absence of a class `Thing`. `Thing` has the same `status`, `expires_on`, and `gateway` methods in it's public interface.

The question is, how can I write something like `@thing ||= Thing.new` in the case where `@thing` is either `nil` or `NoThing` ?

Comment: unfortunately only 2 things are "falsey" in ruby `nil` and `false`. Everything else is considered "truthy" so `@thing` cannot be a `NoThing` when using `||=` because a `NoThing` is a "truthy" thing.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14449380/3982562

Comment: If you intend on using a Null Object pattern then you are already good to go otherwise why not just return a new `Thing` rather than a `NoThing` from what ever call is handling this generation in the first place. Additionally an empty `Thing` with accessor methods could act like both a `Thing` and a `NoThing` without issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could maybe* crib from [FalseClass](https://ruby-doc.org/core/FalseClass.html) and set the same operator methods on `NoThing`. But I'd hesitate to do so for a number of reasons.

Unlike some other languages, Ruby is *very* clear that there are a very limited set of things which are false, `false` and `nil`. Messing with that will probably lead to confusion and bugs down the road, it's probably not worth the bit of convenience you're looking for.

Furthermore, the Null Object Pattern is about returning an object that has the same interface as an object which does something, but it does nothing. Making it appear `false` would defeat that. The desire to write `@thing ||= Thing.new` clashes with the desire for a Null Object. You always want `@thing` set even if `Thing.new` returns `NoThing`, that's what Null Objects are for. The code using the class doesn't care if it's using `Thing` or `NoThing`.

Instead, for those cases when you want to distinguish between `Thing` and `NoThing`, I'd suggest having little method, for example `#nothing?`. Then set `Thing#nothing?` to return `false` and `NoThing#nothing?` to return `true`. This allows you to distinguish between them by asking rather than piercing encapsulation by hard coding class names.

```
class NoThing
  def status
     :cancelled
  end

  def expires_on
     0.days.from_now
  end

  def gateway
    ""
  end

  def nothing?
    true
  end
end

class Thing
  attr_accessor :status, :expires_on, :gateway
  def initialize(args={})
    @status = args[:status]
    @expires_on = args[:expires_on]
    @gateway = args[:gateway]
  end

  def nothing?
    false
  end
end
```

Furthermore, it's bad form for `Thing.new` to return anything but a `Thing`. This adds an extra complication to what should be a simple constructor. It shouldn't even return `nil`, it should throw an exception instead.

Instead, use the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) to keep `Thing` and `NoThing` pure and simple. Put the work to decide whether to return a `Thing` or `NoThing` in a `ThingBuilder` or `ThingFactory`. Then you call `ThingFactory.new_thing` to get a `Thing` or `NoThing`.

```
class ThingFactory
  def self.new_thing(arg)
    # Just something arbitrary for example
    if arg > 5
      return Thing.new(
        status: :allgood,
        expires_on: Time.now + 12345,
        gateway: :somewhere
      )
    else
      return NoThing.new
    end
  end
end

puts ThingFactory.new_thing(4).nothing? # true
puts ThingFactory.new_thing(6).nothing? # false
```

Then, if you really need it, the factory can also have a *separate* class method that returns `nil` instead of `NoThing` allowing for `@thing ||= ThingFactory.new_thing_or_nil`. But you shouldn't need it because that's what the Null Object Pattern is for. If you really do need it, use `#nothing?` and the ternary operator.

```
thing = ThingFactory.new_thing(args)
@thing = thing.nothing? ? some_default : thing
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Schwerns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50536443/3982562) already explains why you should not try to write a custom falsy class. I just want to pass you a quick and relatively simple alternative.

You could add a method on both *Thing* and *NoThing* that evaluates the instance:

```
class Thing
  def thing?
    true
  end
end
```

```
class NoThing
  def thing?
    false
  end
end
```

Now you can assign `@thing` in the following way:

```
@thing = Thing.new unless @thing&.thing?
```

This assumes `@thing` has always either *NilClass*, *Thing* or *NoThing* class.

---

Alternatively you can also override the [*Object#itself*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-itself) method in *NoThing*. This however could produce unwanted results if used by people who don't expect the differing result of *#itself*.

```
class NoThing
  def itself
    nil
  end
end
```

```
@thing = @thing.itself || Thing.new
# or
@thing.itself || @thing = Thing.new # exact ||= mimic
```