# Does if call == method?

Tags: ruby

I just found out that Ruby provides no way to override boolean conversion method.([How to create an Object who act as a False in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444975/how-to-create-an-object-who-act-as-a-false-in-ruby))

I am trying to create an object, and track whenever it is passed to an `if` condition.

However, when I executed the following piece of code, 2222222222222222 wasn't being printed.

```
class Null
  def ==(other)
    p 2222222222222222
    p caller
    super
  end
end

null = Null.new

if null
end
```

Does this mean that `if` doesn't call `==`? Is there a method that `if` calls in an object to evaluate the Truth-yness of it?

Alternatively, is there a way to track where `if object` is used for `object`?

I'm making a large scale change and it would be unreasonable to string search all `if` conditions in our code base. I'd much rather create a special object and log/alert whenever `if object` is used.

Comment: It's weird. You cite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444975/how-to-create-an-object-who-act-as-a-false-in-ruby but then proceed as if you hadn't read the answer.

Comment: @EricNa : There is no reason why `if` needs to call the `==` on its argument. This is up to the implementation. My guess that it simply tests whether the argument after evaluation is either `nil` or `false`. Both - nil and false - have a unique object ID, so it's reasonable to assume that the byte code generated by an `if` statement tetsts these special object ids. The same applies for the ternery conditional operator, i.e. `cond ? expr1 : expr2`.

Comment: Depending on your scenario the [null-object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) might be a good solution. **It does not evaluate to a falsy value**, but implements the same interface as your other object(s). Handling the "nothing" scenario. An example is the Rails [`none`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none) method which returns a null-object (implementing all the query methods).

Answer (score 1):

There are only ever two objects considered "falsey": `nil` and `false`. Everything else is truthy.

So no, `if my_obj` doesn't call `my_obj#==` nor anything else. As long as the object is neither `nil` nor `false`, it's evaluated as true.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to track if an object is "evaluated as boolean", or used in `if` or `unless`.

An equivalent of `if my_obj` would be:

```
unless my_obj.equal? nil || my_obj.equal? false
  # code
end
```

Comment: There's no "cast as boolean" method in Ruby like there is in C++ with `operator bool()`, so I don't believe you can override the "truthiness" of an object.